# How to get certain section that contains some variable with regex in Java?

Tags: java, regex, string

This is my string that contains N foo sections:

```java
var s = "[foo]\n" +
  "one two three\n" +
  "four five six\n" +
  "[foo]\n" +
  "one two three\n" +
  "four five six\n" +
  "[foo]\n" +
  "!BAR\n" +
  "one two three\n" +
  "four five six\n" +
  "[foo]\n" +
  "one two three\n" +
  "four five six";
```

How can I get whole `foo` section, that contains `!BAR` using regex. By other words I need to get this piece:

```
[foo]
!BAR
one two three
four five six
```

Could anyone help me?

Comment: Not sure  why this was closed. It seems perfectly clear to me. This regex works: `Pattern.compile("\\[foo]\n!BAR.*?(?=\\[foo]|\\z)", Pattern.DOTALL)`

Comment: Have a look at https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/, closed because the problem is not clear, with code or expression or anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use a regular expression, this one works:

```
var s = "[foo]\n" +
        "one two three\n" +
        "four five six\n" +
        "[foo]\n" +
        "one two three\n" +
        "four five six\n" +
        "[foo]\n" +
        "!BAR\n" +
        "one two three\n" +
        "four five six\n" +
        "[foo]\n" +
        "one two three\n" +
        "four five six";
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("\\[foo]\n!BAR.*?(?=\\[foo]|\\z)", Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher m = regex.matcher(s);
System.out.println(m.find());
System.out.println(m.group());
/*
 * Output:
 * true
 * [foo]
 * !BAR
 * one two three
 * four five six
 */
```

Breaking it down:

1. `\\[foo]` matches the literal string `"[foo]"`.

   1. The backslash (`\`) is needed to interpret the left square bracket (`[`) literally. Otherwise, it will be interpreted as the start of a [character class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#classes) in the pattern.
   2. Because a backslash begins an escape sequence in a Java String literal, it needs to be doubled in the source code to pass a single backslash to the pattern compiler.
2. `\n` inserts a literal newline character into the pattern, which matches the newline at the end of the section header.
3. `!BAR` matches the literal string `"!BAR"`. This assumes that it's on the next line after the section header, as in the example.
4. `.*?` matches any sequence of characters, including an empty one:

   1. `.` matches [any single character](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#predef). Because the pattern is compiled with the [`Pattern.DOTALL`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL) flag, this includes newlines
   2. `*` modifies the previous pattern to match zero or more times, so any number of any character.
   3. `?` modifies that to make it [reluctant](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#reluc), meaning that it will match the shortest substring possible while still allowing the remainder of the pattern to match. Without this, the pattern would match multiple sections.
5. `(?=\\[foo]|\\z)` creates a [zero-width positive lookahead](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#special). This means that the pattern inside the `(?=` and `)` delimiters must match a substring following the match for the rest of the pattern. The substring matching this part of the pattern does not become part of the match for  the pattern as a whole. To put it another way, this tells the pattern how to recognize where it should stop matching in the original string.

   1. `\\[foo]` as before, matches the literal string `"[foo]"`. This stops the match at the start of the next section.
   2. `|` acts as a [logical "or" operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#logical).
   3. `\\z` matches the [end of the input string](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#bounds). This allows the pattern to match if the section containing `"!BAR"` is the last section of the input string. Not strictly necessary for the example above, but without this, if you delete the last section from the input string, the pattern will fail to match.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is only one `[foo]` section containing `!BAR`, you could get what you want using methods of the String class :

```
public static String getBARSection(String str){
    //removing [foo] sections after the section containing !BAR
    str = str.substring(0,str.indexOf("[foo]",str.indexOf("!BAR")));
    //removing sections before the section containing !BAR
    str = str.substring(str.lastIndexOf("[foo]"));
    return str;
}
```